# Bind click event to future instances of a class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to bind a `click` event in jQuery to all instances of a class, including ones that will be created after page load.

I have the following components:

### HTML

```
<table id='draft-board'>
    <tbody> 
        <tr id='1'>
            <td class='x'><img src='images/x.png' /></td>
            <td class='check available'><img src='images/checkmark.png' /></td>
            <td class='rank'>1</td>
            <td class='player'>Last, First</td>
        </tr>

. . .
```

### Javascript

```
/*** this one works fine ***/
$('#draft-board tbody tr').on('click', 'td.x', function() {
    //do something...
    $(this).addClass('undo').removeClass('x');
});

/*** this one doesn't get triggered ***/
$('draft-board tbody tr').on('click', 'td.undo', function() {
    console.log('clicked undo');
    //do something else...
    $(this).addClass('x').removeClass('undo');
});
```

As you can see, when the user clicks a table cell with the class `x`, I `do something` and then swap class `x` with class `undo`. **This part works fine.**

The part that *doesn't* work is the second block, where I try to `do something else` when the user clicks a table cell with class `undo`. As you can see, I try to log "clicked undo" to the console within that block to see if the `on('click'...)` event is even getting fired...it's not.

My understanding was that the new way to replicate the depreciated `live()` function in jQuery was to call `.on()` on a parent element, then pass in the targeted child element in the parameters of the method, as I've done.

Clearly, however, my table cells which have class `undo` added to them after the page has already loaded are not getting that `.on()` event bound to them.

Thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `#` from your selector on the second handler.

`$('draft-board tbody tr')` -> `$('#draft-board tbody tr')`

Comment: Wow, so I am! Thank you. That's a sign that I've been looking at this code for way too long. Now there's a new problem: it's firing the second block of code even when it's supposed to be firing the first block. I'm guessing it's all happening simultaneously...

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior in this fiddle, it appears to be working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/XBQgh/

Comment: Got it working by changing `$('#draft-board tbody tr')` to `$('#draft-board')`. Who knows why? Thanks Jason!

Comment: Glad I could help. I generally try to make the selectors as simple as possible. Also, doing `$('#draft-board tbody tr')` causes an event handler to be bound to each `tr`, whereas `$('#draft-board')` only binds one handler.

Comment: Yep totally makes sense. I originally had the more detailed selector because I thought the `on()` selector param could only be a direct child of the element you're binding the handler to. (Apparently that isn't the case!)